# Show that $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is a torsion $\mathbb{Z}$ module

Tags: ring-theory, modules, cyclic-groups

What I know is that I should prove  $\forall \bar{x}\in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ , $\exists n\in \mathbb{Z}$ (non-zero) such that $n\bar{x}=0$

How can I do it ?

$\bar{x}$ can only be $\bar{0}$ , $\bar{1}$ , or $\bar{2}$ , right ?

So if I choose $n=3y$ where y is an integer , will it be helpful ?

Comment: Right.  Yes, as long as $y\ne0$

Comment: Both nonzero elements have order $3$.